# Can the Chef package resource accept a data bag?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a group of packages that would be nice to add to a data bag in order to install them all. Is it possible to use the package resource with a data bag?

EDIT: For instance - this is how I'm doing it with the chocolatey resource:

```
workstation_apps = data_bag_item('winapps','desktop_apps')

chocolatey_package workstation_apps['apps']
```

This is the data bag structure:

```
{
  "id": "desktop_apps",
  "apps": [
   "slack",
   "putty",
   "jre8",
   "python2",
   "ruby",
   "chefdk",
   "vmwarevsphereclient",
   "vmwareworkstation",
   "vagrant",
   "terraform",
   "packer",
   "visualstudiocode",
   "pushbullet",
 ]
}
```

This works with the "chocolatey" resource - but will it work with the standard package resource on linux (yum)?

Comment: Please add your code, at least as far as you got with that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - it's all just code.

You can extract such information from a data bag and pass the list of package names as list to the `package` resource.

Comment: Ok - added my code for a similar situation that works - will that work with package?

Comment: Yes, sure, this will work as well.. Not sure, what's more efficient - posting it here or just giving it a try. Or do you see any particular challenge here?

Comment: Excellent - thanks! Not in a place where I can try it right now :) The only other challenge is that I need to specify specify versions of packages. Not sure what that data bag structure should look like.

Comment: You can use a ruby hash for that. I'm not sure, how the `yum` resource handles this, but for `apt`, the `version` parameter is ignored.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what that hash would look like? Yum does honor the version field.

Comment: It helps to understand that data bags aren't a magic Chef construct. They're json stored on the Chef Server. In your chocolatey example you're extracting an array from the json to provide the chocolatey resource with an array of strings. It would be equally valid to declare the array in your recipe and reference it; the resource doesn't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really passing the package resource here "a data bag" you're passing it an Array which you've pulled out of a data_bag.  The package provider doesn't know anything about the data_bag that you're using.

What you're doing is no different than `chocolatey_package [ "slack", "putty" .... ]`.  To do versions you need to pass it an identical length array of versions:

```
package [ "slack", "putty", "jre8" ] do
  version [ nil, "1.2.3", nil ]
end
```

You should probably store that as `name, version` pairs in a hash in a databag, and then extract keys and values as arrays. to give to the package provider.